# Decryption error while Decrypt the symmetric key

Tags: encryption, base64, rsa, badpaddingexception, pkcs

I'm trying to use `RSA` algorithm and `PKCS1Padding` for encryption the given password but when `cipher.doFinal()` is called the `BadPaddingException` is thrown.

Here is the code :

```
String rsaKeyAlgorithm = "RSA";
String rsaEncryptAlgorithm = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

PrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyFactory.getInstance(rsaKeyAlgorithm).generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(rsaEncryptAlgorithm);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
System.out.println(new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes)));
```

I've also reading some articles about encryption by specific provider for example `SUN` may cause `BadPaddingException` because different `Java` versions may have not the specific provider and removed the provider from the `KeyFactory.getInstance` method. But now have issue about how default (non-specific) provider on this method is handling the different `Java` versions on different environments ?

Comment: The exception can have various causes, e.g. wrong key, wrong padding, corrupted ciphertext. Post the encryption code and if possible non-productive sample data.

Comment: The code and config files are same in both productive and development. working on development well but on productive not work and gives exception.

Comment: @Topaco I got a guess.. when i generate the hibernate-key file and then encrypt passwords and copying both hibernate-key and keystore file on productive code from development. Everything works fine! But i shouldn't create hibernate-key file everytime.. So what is going on ? Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending about two days finally my issue get solved! the problem was in generating and copying the keys (hibernate-keystore.key) file also those keys create each time so entering previous passwords get `badPaddingException` because they aren't in keystore file anymore.